# Replace part of string with a letter?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord.js

I am new to programming bots for Discord, but I'm quickly learning the ropes.
My question is as follows:

I have created a function that replaces all characters in a randomly chosen word, into *
Now I check if a given letter is part of the converted word, and returns how many times it occurs.

Now is where I struggle! I want to show the *'s, but I also want to convert back the letter(s) in the word, that are a match.

Sort of like this:

```
let word = 'emoticon';
let string = convert(word); // returns * * * * * * * *
if (checkChar(letter, word) > 0 ) {
  message.channel.send(`${letter} is found XX number of time(s)`);
  // Code to convert the word back to * * o * * * o * if o was the given letter
  message.channel.send(`${newword} here is a clue!`);
}
else {
  message.channel.send(`${letter} is not found!`);
}
```

If anyone can help me achieve this, I'd be forever grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the replace method and passing it a callback to do a more sophisticated check. Here I remember the original word to check then the letter against it while I move though the hidden word index by index.

```js
const original = 'some word'
let hidden = original.replace(/./g, '*')
console.log(hidden) // *********

let testLetter = 'o'
hidden = hidden.replace(/./g, (c, i) => original[i] === testLetter ? testLetter : c)
console.log(hidden) // "*o****o**"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I rewrote my code and am now one step closer to the finishline :D